# Views slideshow z-index

Tags: views, navigation, theming

I have view slideshow setup (with [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module)  to display some fields (image, title, node teaser) on very top of content area on front page. Also i have drop-down menu setup (with [nice menu](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) module). 
Now, when menu is expanded it goes over slideshow fields, but when slideshow auto-rotates it then position it self in front of menu and never go back again (until i reload page). I tried to solve this with z-index with no luck.

here is a screen shot when image go in front of menu.
[image]

Any one had same problem? Can any one point me in right direction?

Comment: I'm not expert on this issue but I did have a similar issue with my slideshow.  z-index acts weird, with absolute/relative position and floats,  I had to my issue with trial and error.   Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: can you provide a URL?

Comment: Did you try putting a max-width on it/overflow:hidden?  Or, are all of the parent divs/classes in relation to the menu positioned too?  It is total trial and error though.

Comment: Thanks all for comments & help. 
I solved problem with adding some more z-index style def on wrapper tags until i found one that did the trick.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment (Nebojsa Jul 24 '11 at 20:13) helped me to solve the same problem. I had to set the z-index of .navbar-collapse.collapse to 20 (more than 5).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "display: relative" to the outer div that wraps the slideshow.

Comment: There is no "relative" option for "display" property. Do you mean "position: relative" ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS by setting the position to relative and the `z-index` to `-1`, refer this code:

```
#views_slideshow_cycle_main_special_collection_slideshow-block {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of wrapper tags (e.g. .navbar-collapse.collapse) to a value greater then 3.

None of the wrapper tags of the dropwdown menu should have a z-index of less then 4. I set .navbar-collapse.collapse to 20 to get it work.